# Is it compulsory to give name according to Rashi in Hinduism?

Tags: astrology, name, rashi

Is it Compulsory  to give name(to Baby) according to Rashi (राशि) in Hinduism ?

Comment: In hinduism baby's "Nakshatra" is determined by the moon's position at the time of her birth. Sun signs, known as rashi in Indian astrology, are based on the position of the sun. There are 12 sun signs or rashis in all. 

Indian astrologers use  baby's rashi along with her "Nakshatra" to paint a more complete picture of her personality. Rashis or sun signs are the more common form of astrology used in the Western world.

Comment: Not mandatory. All members of our family are named with letter "अ" or "A" after our Kuladevata and this has nothing to with Rashi. So, i think this is not mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Depends.

In earlier days, people doesn't used to record the day of Birth, even if they do many are not educated enough to remember those 60 Lunar years (after which it is believed in Hinduism that we would have similar years).

So, naming after the nakshatra/rashi helped them track things, without having to search through documents available at the village intellectual.

These days, I have seen people keeping a middle name based on nakshatra & dropping it in official records.

Regards
Narendra N